# Non linear first order ODE on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system of ODEs 
$$\left\{ \begin{matrix} x' = y^2, & x(0) = x_0\\ y' = x^2, & y(0) = y_0  \end{matrix} \right. $$

where $x, y :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}.$
I wonder whether there is a "known formula" for the solution of such systems.

Thank you for any information

Comment: You are likely stuck with numerical methods or qualitative methods (critical points, phase portrait, etc.).

Comment: I think you are completely right Moo ...the integral is a bit complicated

Answer (score 3):

This system considered as

$$
\dot x = g(y)\\
\dot y = g(x)
$$

can be handled by dividing both equations giving

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{g(x)}{g(y)}
$$

which is separable

Attached a stream plot for

$$
\dot x = y^2\\
\dot y = x^2
$$

with a typical solution in red

$$
y^3-x^3 = C_0
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer

Comment: Would it be possible to write $C_0$ in terms of $x_0$ and $y_0$ ?

Comment: @A.PI Yes. Supposing that the solution passes by $x_0,y_0$ then $C_0 = y_0^3-x_0^3$

Comment: Oh sure if the trajectory passes $(x_0, y_0)$ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this
$$\frac  {dx}{dy}=\frac {y^2}{x^2}$$
$$\implies x^3=y^3+K$$

Comment: Thank you for this answer